# Jquery Select on select

Tags: jquery

I want to call a function on selecting a checkbox,

```
jQuery('#check_box').on('click', function(){
    isFormComplete();
});
```

in function `isFormComplete` i am checking for all the values of form, if it is complete, while, i'm calling this function on clicking checkbox, so, in function, it has the null value of checkbox. Is there a way , the function is called, after checkbox is selected, that is `isFormComplete` has the checked value of checkbox

**UPDATE**

Consider, this is my function

```
function isFormComplete(){
  allOk = true;
  if (!jQuery('#check_box').is(':checked')) {
    allOk = false;
   }
 }
```

But `allOk` returns false, instead, un-checking the checkbox returns true

Comment: remove the ! from the if condition, it negates the condition

Comment: question updated, the function is like this, it was my mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `:checked` selector in jquery. Use `.is()` is to check the checkbox is selected or not it returns boolean

```
jQuery('#check_box').on('click', function(){
    if(jQuery(this).is(":checked")){
        isFormComplete(); // if it is checked 
    }
    else{
        callANotherFunction() // if it is unchecked or empty
    }
});
```

Comment: Please give the sample with if you are using?

Comment: As isFormComplete() is called on click event, more like during click event, so in function isFormComplete, it has the previous value of checkbox... i.e, not clicked

Comment: yes, absolutely correct, let me update my question, for more clarification

Comment: my answer is simple way if it is check call one function else call another function

Comment: finally, it is working, it was some other silly mistake, but your jsfiddle helped me in that

Answer (score 1):

Know its answered but, you don't have to wrap to jquery element, and you can bind the event to the change event. IMO it feels safer and faster

```
jQuery('#check_box').change(function() {
    if(this.checked) {
      isFormComplete();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
if($(this).is(":checked")) {

}
```